# Show that the function is of class $C^1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(0,0)=0$
and $f(x,y)= \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}$,  if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Show that $f$ is of class $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

If we use the definition of continuity then it becomes quite messy.Is there another way to prove it?

Thanks

Comment: hint $|x^2 - y^2| \le x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: It is indeed messy but not technically difficult, just give it more patience.

Comment: @user251257 Can you please elaborate a little? Something is going wrong with my calculations.

Comment: using the hint and you obtain $|f(x,y)| \le |xy| \to 0$ for $(x,y)\to 0$. Thus, $f$ is continuous at $0$.  For the other points argue by composition of continuous functions.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!